# How to generate PDF in Salesforce Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, pdf

I created a button to link to a PDF Visualforce Page (one that uses `<apex:page renderAs="PDF">`) in Classic Salesforce. But now I want the same effect in Salesforce Lightning Experience. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Good question. Will be interesting to see if there is a clear cut technique to use amongst https://www.google.ie/search?q=generate+pdf+lightning. (Generally best if you show some research effort yourself in the question though.)

Comment: I don't have any clue to solve this problem. search no answer by google.

Comment: Can you expand your question to say exactly what you want a PDF of? And are you looking for something built in the general Lightning Experience UI or are you OK with coding something yourself?

Comment: Thanks.I am a Chinese. Maybe describe this question not clear. I create a button  to link to a PDF Visualforce Page in classic Salesforce.  use "<apex:page renderAs="PDF""> to generate PDF in Salesforce classic experience. but now I want to same effect in Salesforce Lightning experience.

Comment: I've edited your question to include that new information.

Comment: Your help was greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently lightning framework doesn't provide you an option like renderas pdf in vf page out of the box for lightning components.To generate Pdf in lightning you can opt for either of the three approaches.

1. Using VF page that renders as pdf in a Lightning component with Iframe 
   approach
2. Use a button to open a url from lightning component to open a vf page which renders the pdf like below.
3. Using a java script library like **jsPDF** to render the html into pdf.

**Code Sample for 2nd Approach:**

```
    var baseUrl= decodeURIComponent(window.location.hostname);
    var url = ' https://'+baseUrl+'/apex/Export_To_PDF?param1='+objId;
    window.open(url);
```

There is no right or wrong approach solely depends on your use case. My personal opinion though would be using the **1St approach** or **2nd approach** as this is really easy to implement

Comment: Much appreciated!

Comment: I got same requirement and came up with simple OOB workaround; adding as comment as this Question is closed. We can have printable view button on layout which will let you download as PDF in LEX: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring19/release-notes/rn_printable_view.htm

Answer (score 0):

As of now, you can only generate PDF using visualforce page and those pages can be used in lightning very easily using a button or a link, and if you want to put that visualforce page in a lightning component, then you can use iFrame(I don't recommend you using this functionality). Instead of this override a visualforce page on a custom detail button and that button can be put in the lightning layout.